# Element text content not changing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to make a functional timer that counts down from 15 or 30. However I cannot get to the  text value to change upon click of the 15 button. Can someone diagnose this issue?

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<h1 id="timer"><time>00</time></h1>
<button id="fifteen">15 sec</button>
```

JavaScript or Jquery

```
var fifteen = document.getElementById('timer');

fifteen.onclick = fifteenRollback();

function fifteenRollback(){
    h1.textcontent = "15";
}
```

Comment: It's `fifteen.onclick = fifteenRollback`, and note that `h1` is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it using mentioned jQuery library:

```
$('#fifteen').on('click', function() {
  $('#timer').text('15');
});
```